# multiple authentication methods with same REST resources

Tags: rest, http, authentication, api-design

Let's suppose you are building  REST APIs which will be accessed from different kinds of consumers (human users, things, untrusted native apps) so each of them has its own authentication method, for technical or "historical" decisions.

For instance, users use JWTs with some claims model while native apps are authorized with Oauth2 flow and use OAuth tokens. Both though want to access the same endpoints, so the application needs to distinguish between different  models of  authentication information and route them to appropriate services

It would be easy to add an HTTP header "X-Auth-Method" and check it at every incoming request, but I'm asking myself if it would be RESTful enough and, above all, causes a problem for third-party consumers that want to integrate their software and must know/implement some sort of vendor-specific behavior.

Another solution would be to provide a different root endpoint

- api.myapp.com/v1/userapi
- api.myapp.com/v1/clientapi

and then let API gateway route requests to appropriate auth service verification step, but actually both expose exactly the same APIs.

What would be more correct in a RESTful way and being aware of all concerns that come when you build open ecosystems?